# Why is my DQN (Deep Q Network) not learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am training a DQN (Deep Q Network) on a CartPole problem from OpenAI's gym, but when I start the training, the total score from an episode decreases, instead of increasing. I don't know if it is helpful but I noticed that the AI prefers one action over the another and refuses to do anything else (unless it is forced by the epsilon greedy strategy), at least for some time. I tried my best, but I just can't figure out what is going on.

Here is my code:

```
import torch as t
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as f

import random as r


class QNet:
    def predict(self, x: t.Tensor) -> t.Tensor:
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def copy_weights(origin: [], target: []):
        for origin_layer, target_layer in zip(origin, target):
            target_layer.weight = nn.Parameter(origin_layer.weight.clone())


class Memory:
    def __init__(self, state: t.Tensor, next_state: t.Tensor, action: int, reward: float):
        self.state = state
        self.next_state = next_state
        self.action = action
        self.reward = reward


class ReplayMemory:
    def __init__(self, capacity: int):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.memories = []

    def add_memory(self, memory: Memory):
        self.memories.append(memory)

        if len(self.memories) > self.capacity:
            self.memories.pop(0)

    def get_batch(self, size: int):
        if len(self.memories) < size:
            raise Exception("There are not enough memories to make a batch.")

        start_index = r.randint(0, len(self.memories) - size)
        end_index = start_index + size
        return self.memories[start_index:end_index]


class QLearning:
    def __init__(self, net: QNet, target_net: QNet, optimizer, gamma: float):
        self.net = net
        self.target_net = target_net
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.gamma = gamma

    def train(self, batch: [Memory]):
        batched_pred = []
        batched_opt_pred = []
        for sample in batch:
            pred = self.net.predict(sample.state)

            opt_pred = pred.clone()
            opt_pred[sample.action] = sample.reward
            if sample.next_state is not None:
                opt_pred[sample.action] += t.max(self.target_net.predict(sample.next_state)) * self.gamma

            batched_pred.append(pred)
            batched_opt_pred.append(opt_pred)

        loss = f.mse_loss(t.stack(batched_pred), t.stack(batched_opt_pred))
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
```

```
import gym

from qlearning import *

env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
state = t.tensor(env.reset(), dtype=t.float)


class Agent(nn.Module, QNet):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.l1 = nn.Linear(4, 32)
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(32, 16)
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(16, 8)
        self.l4 = nn.Linear(8, 4)
        self.l5 = nn.Linear(4, 2)

    def predict(self, x):
        y = f.relu(self.l1(x))
        y = f.relu(self.l2(y))
        y = f.relu(self.l3(y))
        y = f.relu(self.l4(y))
        return self.l5(y)


agent = Agent()
target_agent = Agent()
q = QLearning(agent, target_agent, optim.Adam(agent.parameters(), lr=0.001), 0.9)
replay_memory = ReplayMemory(100000)
epsilon = 1
epsilon_dec = 1 / 1000
total_reward = 0
for i in range(1000):
    env.render()

    action = 0
    if r.random() > epsilon:
        action = t.argmax(agent.predict(state)).item()
    else:
        action = env.action_space.sample()

    epsilon -= epsilon_dec

    next_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    next_state = t.tensor(next_state, dtype=t.float)
    if done:
        reward = -1
        replay_memory.add_memory(Memory(state, None, action, reward))
    else:
        replay_memory.add_memory(Memory(state, next_state, action, reward))

    total_reward += reward

    if done:
        state = t.tensor(env.reset(), dtype=t.float)

        # print(int(total_reward))
        total_reward = 0

    if len(replay_memory.memories) >= 10:
        q.train(replay_memory.get_batch(10))

    if i % 10:
        QNet.copy_weights([agent.l1, agent.l2, agent.l3, agent.l4, agent.l5],
                          [target_agent.l1, target_agent.l2, target_agent.l3, target_agent.l4, target_agent.l5])

    state = next_state
env.close()
```

Comment: Could you add some plots showing your loss and rewards

Comment: @desert_ranger I have already solved the problem in the PyTorch forum a long time ago. The problem was that I haven’t train it long enough.